# Issue to set textarea height to height of tab-content-size

Tags: javafx, textarea, fxml

My issue is to set the textarea height to the tab-content-size, but the textarea takes only a part of the content.

I tried different values as maxvalue for maxHeight-property and prefHeight, but no success. There's no problem with the width, its fits the tab-content. Thanks for your help!

The main program:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(Main.class, (java.lang.String[])null);
    } 
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        String resourcePath = "resources/fxml/ExampleFZ.fxml";
        URL location = Main.class.getResource(resourcePath);
        try {
            VBox page = (VBox) FXMLLoader.load(location);
            Scene scene = new Scene(page);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Example FZ");
            primaryStage.show();            
        } catch(Exception ex)  {Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The FXML-Code:

```
<VBox fx:id="rootBox" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.ExampleFZcontroller">
<children>
  <GridPane>
    <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="70.0" minWidth="70.0" prefWidth="70.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    </rowConstraints>
     <children>
        <Button fx:id="myButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#myButtonClicked" text="Button" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" />            
     </children>
  </GridPane>
  <TabPane fx:id="myTabPane" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
     <tabs>
        <Tab fx:id="myTab" text="MyTab">
           <content>
              <TextArea fx:id="myTextArea" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" text="myText" />
           </content></Tab>
     </tabs></TabPane>
</children>
<stylesheets>
  <URL value="@../css/ExampleFZ.css" />
</stylesheets>
</VBox>
```

The Controller-Code:

```
public class ExampleFZcontroller {
    @FXML
    VBox rootBox;
    @FXML
    private Button myButton;
    @FXML
    private TabPane myTabPane;
    @FXML
    private Tab myTab;
    @FXML
    private TextArea myTextArea;    
    @FXML
    void myButtonClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        myTextArea.appendText("\nonce again");
    }
}
```

The css-file:

```
.tab-header-background {
   -fx-background-color: grey ;                             
.text-area  {
   -fx-border-width: 5px;
   -fx-border-color: red ;
}[enter image description here][1]
```

this is the result (see the image):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text area is filling the tab's content; the problem is that the tab pane is not growing when the window increases size. You can fix this with the `VBox` layout constraint [`vgrow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html#setVgrow-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.scene.layout.Priority-):

```xml
<TabPane fx:id="myTabPane" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
    <tabs>
        <Tab fx:id="myTab" text="MyTab">
            <content>
                <TextArea fx:id="myTextArea" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" 
                     text="myText" />
            </content>
         </Tab>
     </tabs>
</TabPane>
```